# Hibernate, how do I get the custom type to register

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Apparently it's possible to [create a TypeDef that can switch implement implementations based on dialect](https://zorq.net/b/2012/04/21/switching-hibernates-uuid-type-mapping-per-database).

```
package org.hibernate.type;

import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaTypeDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.UUIDTypeDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.SqlTypeDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class UUIDCustomType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 902830399800029445L;

private static final SqlTypeDescriptor  SQL_DESCRIPTOR;
private static final JavaTypeDescriptor TYPE_DESCRIPTOR;

static {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        properties.load( loader.getResourceAsStream( "database.properties" ) );
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( "Could not load properties!", e );
    }

    String dialect = properties.getProperty( "dialect" );
    if ( dialect.equals( "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" ) ) {
        SQL_DESCRIPTOR = PostgresUUIDType.PostgresUUIDSqlTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
    } else if(dialect.equals("org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect")) {
        SQL_DESCRIPTOR = VarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
    } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported database!");
    }

    TYPE_DESCRIPTOR = UUIDTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
}

public UUIDCustomType() {
    super(SQL_DESCRIPTOR, TYPE_DESCRIPTOR);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "uuid-custom";
}

}
```

my problem is that hibernate doesn't seem to recognize it, it's worth noting that at one point I made "uuid-custom" a static string in the type and referenced that directly in the `@Type`, so it's not like it's not actually on the classpath.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: uuid-custom
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.fillSimpleValue(SimpleValueBinder.java:510)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.SetSimpleValueTypeSecondPass.doSecondPass(SetSimpleValueTypeSecondPass.java:42)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processSecondPassesOfType(Configuration.java:1470)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1418)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>       ... 45 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load Class [uuid-custom]
>       at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.classForName(StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.java:60)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.fillSimpleValue(SimpleValueBinder.java:491)
>       ... 50 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uuid-custom
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
>       at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.classForName(StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.java:57)

what else do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to get it to work otherwise, but adding it to a typedef in `package-info.java` fixes the problem

```
@TypeDef(
    name = UUIDCustomType.UUID,
    defaultForType = UUID.class,
    typeClass = UUIDCustomType.class
)
package com.xenoterracide.rpf.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.type.UUIDCustomType;

import java.util.UUID;
```

Comment: UUIDCustomType.UUID ? this gives me compilation error

Comment: looking at the code, it's just a reference to the same string "getName" returns.